# Get values from mysql table into dropdown menu (undefined variable)

Tags: php, html, mysqli

this is probably a very simple question to solve, however I've been stuck with this for a while and I can't figure out for the life of me what's wrong with my code. It may be just a syntax mistake but I've gathered this code from other questions and it should work but I keep getting the errors : - Undefined variable : mysqli and - Call to a member function query() of a non-object , both in the line "$result = $mysqli->query($sql);".

Here's the snippet of my code where I have the dropdown menu set up.

```html
<label class="control-label" for="formInput85">Professor</label>
                                           
<?php

$sql = "SELECT name FROM professores";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

echo "<select class=".'"form-control"'.">";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

And here's my code in the very beginning of the page, that is connecting to my database in phpmyadmin.

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['name'];
 
 $servername = "localhost"; 
 $username = "root"; 
 $password = ""; 
 $dbname = "teste"; 

 $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname); 
?>
```

Thank you for your help! If you have any tips on how to send the value selected into another row of the table I gladly appreciate it as it will be my next step :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$mysqli` is not the right variable in this case. So this line:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

has to become

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Exactly what I needed :P I didn't realize mysqli was the connection variable, oh well the more you know :)
Any tips on sending the selected value into a table?

Comment: @Joe you're welcome ;)